# How to convert JSP request attribute to a string and assign it to an object in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I have a Java servlet which sets an attribute on the HttpServletRequest object:

```
request.setAttribute("SOME_STRING", somestring);
```

Now, in my page.jsp, I want to set this string to be displayed in an HTML textarea...

I've been trying to do something like this, but I just can't get it to display the string:

```
var somestr = <%= (String) (request.getAttribute("SOME_STRING")) %>;
document.getElementById("my_textarea").value = somestr;
```

The textbox now displays "[Object object]"  instead of the string itself.

How can I get it to display the actual string?

Comment: What do you put at somestring at `request.setAttribute("SOME_STRING", somestring);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change your line from

```
var somestr = <%= (String) (request.getAttribute("SOME_STRING")) %>;
```

to

```
var somestr = '<%= (String) (request.getAttribute("SOME_STRING")) %>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose `var somestr` with single quotations `' '`,

```
var somestr = '<%= (String) (request.getAttribute("SOME_STRING")) %>';//Add ' ' 

document.getElementById("my_textarea").value = somestr;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var attrib ="<%=request.getAttribute("hello") %>";
alert(attrib); 
</script>
```

Enclose your scriptlet with quotes.